# "File limit of 90 seconds" is actually 90 seconds total for all the audio files in that one emit?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

Has anyone else ran into this problem?  I am making a skill that plays audio clips mixed into the alexa speech in each emit.  Amazon's resource site only says that the file's themselves must be under 90 seconds.  In one emit i have 4 files that together exceed 90 seconds, however individually they do not.  The amazon testing environment will return an error saying the total duration exceeds the allowed limit.  Pretty annoying. Is the only solution to break it into multiple emits?

Comment: For the record, that limit has now been extended to 240 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total duration cannot exceed 90 seconds. The documentation is actually pretty explicit about this:

> The audio files you include within your service’s response must be
>   very short to ensure a good user experience. You can include up to
>   five audio files in a single response. The combined total time for all
>   audio files in a single response cannot be more than ninety (90)
>   seconds.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/handling-requests-sent-by-alexa

Comment: yah I saw that little tidbit upon further review!  Makes it tricky to do custom narration voices which is a bit annoying.